# How to access admin side of my web site in phpFox?

Tags: phpfox

I want to access admin panel of my web site in phpFox.

In the case of Joomla! websites we can easy to access admin panel through

www.example.com/administrator same way any idea

about phpFox websites?

Comment: What did the documentation, community, helpdesk, etc. say?

Comment: As above - http://www.phpfox.com/forum/solved-cases-77/admin-url/ (bottom of the page)

Answer (score 2):

```
You can access your admin area in phpfox by using

(1)http://www.example.com/admincp
(2)http://www.example.com/index.php?do=/admincp/
```

Comment: Ah great - Thanks 2 Ankit Agrawal & All